# How to factor $N=14$ with Shor's algorithm?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, shors-algorithm

As a practice exercise, I am trying to factor $N=14$ using Shor's algorithm. My initial guess is $a = 5$, and I need a quantum circuit $U$ for:

$U\vert y \rangle = \vert 5 \cdot y ~{\rm mod}~ 14 \rangle$ for $y=1, 2, \cdots, 13$, i.e. for $y=0001, 0010,  ... , 1101$. The modular arithmetic yields the table:

01 0001 0011 
02 0010 0110 
03 0011 1001 
04 0100 1100 
05 0101 0001 
06 0110 0100 
07 0111 0111 
08 1000 1010 
09 1001 1101 
10 1010 0010 
11 1011 0101 
12 1100 1000 
13 1101 1011

The qiskit examples give a circuit for $N=15$, and
I was able to find a similar circuit for factoring $N=6$ by trial and error. $U\vert y \rangle = \vert 5 \cdot y ~{\rm mod}~ 6 \rangle$ is reproduced by:

[image]

Clearly, trial and error isn't going to work for $N=14$. Is there a systematic method that will provide the circuit I am looking for?

Comment: please delete the duplicate from crypto.stackexchange, I doubt anyone will answer there. this is the right place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shor's algorithm does not apply to even numbers.

(Nor to prime powers. There is a reason why it was first demonstrated for N=15: It is the smallest number it can be applied to.)

Comment: Ahh. I had not appreciated that.

Comment: ... see also my edit. Next should be 21.

Answer (score 3):

The class `algorithms.factorizes.Shor` contains a "private" method `_power_mod_N` that does what you want.  The result isn't pretty, but it does the job.

Alternatively, if you just want to play with a simulator, you might want to look at [quirk](https://%5Bquirk%5D%5Bhttps://algassert.com/quirk%5D.). It includes $B^A mod R$ as a built-in gate.

---

Answering question below:

```
from qiskit.algorithms.factorizers.shor import Shor
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

power = Shor()._power_mod_N(n=4, N=14, a=3)
qc = QuantumCircuit(power.num_qubits)
qc.append(power, range(power.num_qubits))
qc.decompose().draw()
```

The value `n` is $\log_2(N)$, `N` is the number you are factoring, and `a` is the value you're raising to the exponent.  For N=14, this generates code with 12 qubits.  It's really ugly!  Use quirk.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll take a look at _power_mod_N. My primary motivation is to build my own version of $a^x ~{\rm mod}~ N$ for general $a$ and $N$.

Comment: from algorithms.factorizes.Shor import _power_mod_N didn't work. How should I import this private method?

Comment: @RobertSingleton.  See above

Comment: Thanks for your useful example!

Comment: @FankYellin I appreciate the useful comments I have received! I am playing around with quirk, and I have created some simple "a^x mod N" circuits.  However, I cannot seem to extract the gates?!? I would like to insert the gate sequence in a separate python code, so just dragging and dropping gates in a quirk circuit is not quite what I need. Any suggestions? Also: is there a way to insert a figure into this thread?

Comment: Easy question: For actual questions and answers, you can drag and drop an image into the box, and  it will automatically be uploaded to imgur and a link made.  You can change the size of the image using https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs.

Comment: Quirk does not (yet)? have a method to extract the gates. Its design goal (according to Gitney's blog) was to provide immediate and continuous user feedback.  As such, everything internally is either an operator matrix or a permutation (when the entries in the operator matrix are all 0's and 1's).  It doesn't transpile to gates.  So, for example, with Shor's algorithm, you get a good idea of how the algorithm works by assuming that $A^x(mod N)$ exists as a gate, and not caring how such a gate would be implemented.   Sorry if you actually need to build the circuit and I misled you.